# XIM UIM not working Compose Key

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, input-method, compose-key

I am trying to use custom compose key sequences and have read that I need XIM for it (or UIM).
The problem is, Compose Sequences stop working altogether when using it. 
The side effect that it disables ctrl+shift+u unicode entering is supposed to only apply to XIM, so I also tried UIM, but that also has the issue while still not working.
I am using Linux Mint 19.1

Can anyone help me to get custom compose key sequences to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Even though I have read that I have to use xim or uim, selecting them breaks everything.

By not selecting anything and just placing the file ~/.XCompose everything works as intended.